# JS Accordion closes while clicking links inside

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I'm having some issues with keeping the accordion open whilst clicking links within that accordion dropdown. It's a careers page and when I open the individual jobs, I want users to be able to open the application in a new tab.  Any ideas?

https://www.trinovainc.com/careers.html

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-panel careers" data-id="panel-1">
    <div class="accordion">
      <h4><a class="accordion-title">Application Engineer - Mobile, AL<span class="ion-chevron-down"></span></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-panel-content panel-1">
      <p>TriNova is looking for an energetic and personable candidate who is a self-motivated and well-organized professional to join our team as an Application Engineer.</p>
      <h4>Summary</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Provides in-depth product and application knowledge for TriNova and customers; specifically providing inside sales support for account managers. Duties to include reviewing of specifications, verifying model codes, quoting, ordering, expediting and communicating with the customer and sales force.</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <h4>PRIME RESPONSIBILITIES</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Review all types of applications that consist of but not limited to: sizing valves, choosing instruments, sizing gamma, sizing flowmeters and creating electrical &amp; PID drawings for various types of field instrument panels.</li>
            <li>Review specifications and provide model codes for products.</li>
            <li>Perform CAD drawings of best practice installation and wiring</li>
            <li>Communicate with the customer, outside salespeople, manufacturers and the Area Vice President.</li>
            <li>Understand commercial issues and terms.</li>
            <li>Field visits with account managers for relationship development, training and as required to optimize the order process and achieve customer satisfaction</li>
            <li>Improve product and technical knowledge.</li>
            <li>Troubleshooting of basic device issues.</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <h4>MINIMUM EDUCATION</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Bachelor&rsquo;s Degree in Engineering.</li>
            <li>Minor in Sales Engineering is a plus</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <h4>TRAVEL</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Occasional travel required.</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <h4>PREVIOUS JOB EXPERIENCE</h4>
      <h4>Desired:</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Previous related experience of at least 2 years</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <h4>Required:</h4>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <li>None</li>
          <ul></ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <a class="button orange apply" href="https://www.trinovainc.com/job-application.html" target="_blank">Apply Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`:

In Javascript you have event bubbling, which means that whenever an event is fired for an element. That event bubbles up to all the parent elements. This means if you have an onlick for the accordion to close it and you click a button (or anything else) inside of it, it will close. You can prevent this by using `event.stopPropagation()`. This will stop the event from propagating up the DOM structure.

Example:

```js
function prop(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
}

function notProp(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<div id="propagated" onclick="alert('Bubbled')"><button onclick="prop(event)">Click</button></div>

<div id="notpropagated" onclick="alert('OH NO')"><button onclick="notProp(event)">Click</button></div>
```

Comment: @sotechworks Have you figured this out yet? If you need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: I actually haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I'm having some issues on opening the apply button that is sitting inside that accordion.

Comment: 'having some issues'... Are they the same issues described in the question?

Comment: @sotechworks Try adding this to the a tag ('apply button'): `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"`

Comment: Yes, sorry same issues.

Comment: add it to this?
<a class="button orange apply" href="https://www.trinovainc.com/job-application.html" target="_blank">Apply Now</a></div>

Comment: yeah the `a` tag

Comment: @sotechworks so...  `<a class="button orange apply" href="trinovainc.com/job-application.html" target="_blank" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Apply Now</a>`

Comment: @sotechworks, you're most welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark by it. Happy Coding!!